# bash script stops unexpectedly after second run from iscsiadm

Tags: bash, iscsi

iscsiadm stop / leave bash script, i dont know why ?

the "script"

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP=`/sbin/iscsiadm -m node -T ${iSCSI_DEVICE} -p ${IP}:3260 --login 2>/dev/null`
echo "Hallo Welt"
```

on first run it works great
on second run ( iscsiadm run´s in an error ) i´ll never seen "Hallo Welt", i dont know why ?

have any one a solution for it ?

Comment: Try to add set -x before "TMP=..." to enable the debug.

Comment: Hello Wooghie,

TMP get´s some Content, but after this, the execution stops .. the echo command and the following commands would not be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it ..

set -e

wars the bad guy :-).
After removing, the Scripts works fine